# Google App Engine Application - 502 bad gateway error with klein micro web framework

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, klein-mvc

I developed an python webcrawler application based on scrapy and packaged it as a klein application ([klein framework](https://pypi.org/project/klein/))

When I test it locally it everything works as expected, however when I deploy it to google app engine I get a "502 bad gateway". I found other mentions of the 502 error but nothing in relation to the klein framework I am using. So I was just wondering if app engine is maybe incompatible with it.

This is my folder structure

```
    app
    --app.yaml
    --main.py
    --requirements.txt
```

The contents of app.yaml

```
    runtime: python37
    
    instance_class: F2
    
    handlers:
    - url: /.*
      secure: always
      redirect_http_response_code: 301
      script: auto
```

The contents of main.py

```
    from klein import route, run
    
    @route("/")
    def landing_page(request):
        return "HELLO"
    
    if __name__== "__main__":
        run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)
```

Comment: I tried to run this code locally and it works when using the “python” command, but not when using gunicorn, or the other supported [web servers supported by App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup)

You may want Cloud Run to replicate the environment you have locally.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I also started to migrate  to cloud run in the meantime. It does work there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine requires your `main.py` file to declare an `app` variable which corresponds to a [WSGI Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface).

Since Klein is an asynchronous web framework, [it is not compatible with WSGI](https://github.com/twisted/klein/issues/106) (which is synchronous).

Your best option would be to use a service like [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/), which would allow you to define your own runtime and use an asynchronous HTTP server compatible with Klein.